# Pig with oozie workflow

Tags: apache-pig, oozie

I have a wrapper shell script which reads an input file and calls a pig script multiple times. This works fine on the crontab. However, doesn't work when trying to do with oozie engine. How to achieve looping in oozie. If this is not the correct way, can someone suggest alternate methods ? I need to be able to read some parameters from an input file and then for each line (and corresponding read param) call a pig script or pig action multiple times.

---

while read line

```
do
    seedidprefix=$(echo $line |awk -v OFS='\t' '{print $3;}')
    seedaudprefix=$(echo $line |awk -v OFS='\t' '{print $2;}')
    adgrpid=$(echo $line |awk -v OFS='\t' '{print $1;}')
    nwtype=$(echo $line |awk -v OFS='\t' '{print $4;}')
    chainedseedid=$(echo $line |awk -v OFS='\t' '{print $5;}')

if [ $nwtype == "ADX" ]; then

    hadoop jar pig.jar -param segid=${seedaudprefix} -param nw=${nwtype} -param date=${MODELDATE} -param seedid=${seedidprefix} -param audienceId=${adgrpid} -param chainedseedid=${chainedseedid} ${TOP_DIR}/histo_bkup_adx.pig

else

    hadoop jar pig.jar -param segid=${seedaudprefix} -param nw=${nwtype} -param date=${MODELDATE} -param seedid=${seedidprefix} -param audienceId=${adgrpid} -param chainedseedid=${chainedseedid} ${TOP_DIR}/histo_bkup.pig

fi

done<${campaign_file}
```

---

Comment: why are you looping ? can you give data example ?

Answer (score 1):

I came across a similar issue - I needed to execute a pig script a variable number of times.

What worked for me was to use Embedded Pig in Python ([see doc.][1]).

The Oozie workflow has a *pig* action with the *script* pointing to the python file.
Also use the *file* tag to mark the pig script that needs to be repeatedly executed so that it'll get loaded to the working directory (same goes for the file from which the controller, in your case the shell script, reads input).

The Oozie script will look like,

```
<workflow>
    ...        
    <action name="action_1" retry-max="0" retry-interval="1">
        <pig>        
            <script>${path_src}/my_controller.py</script>
            <file>${path_src}/data.txt#data.txt</file>
            <file>${path_src}/my_script.pig#my_script.py</file>
        </pig>
        <ok to="Done"/>
        <error to="Fail"/>
    </action>
    ...
</workflow>
```

The python script will look like,

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from org.apache.pig.scripting import Pig
if __name__ == '__main__' :
    # Load pig parameters - assuming each parameter is in the format KEY = Value
    pigParams = {}
    ipFile = open( 'data.txt', 'r' )
    for line in ipFile :
        if len( line.strip() ) == 0 :
            continue
        fields = line.split( '=' )
        pigParams[ fields[ 0 ].strip() ] = fields[ 1 ].strip()
    ipFile.close()

    for i in range( 10 ) :
        pigScript = Pig.compileFromFile( 'my_script.pig' )
        pigScript.bind( pigParams ).run()
```

Hope this helps.